# Coordinating writes to a texture in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, graphics, parallel-processing, textures, gpu

I am not sure if this is possible. So if it isn't just explain to me why it cannot be done.

I am writing to a 3D texture in a fragment shader through the use of imageStore().

Now, things are working, what I am about to describe is not considered a bug per se.

Due to the way I write to the texture, the same texel may adopt different colors over time since on each frame any thread may be the last thread to write to that texel.

Now, imagine we were doing normal 2D rendering, then I could check the z value written to a texel, compare it to the z value that I am about to write, and if my z value is bigger than the one stored I discard the operation.

Assume I have a similar criteria to determine whether I should overwrite the current value in the texture. How can I actually coordinate the write?

in other words, how can I atomically read the value, check it against the value I am attempting to write and then wrtie it atomically?

Comment: "*in other words, how can I atomically read the value, check it against the value I am attempting to write and then wrtie it atomically?*" But that's not the same as a z-buffer operation. With z-buffers, you have to control *other* writes based on the result of the depth test. You can do an atomic read/test/write in GLSL, but doing an atomic read/modify/write-to-different-value is a whole other matter. So is that what you're trying to do, or do you just want a read/test/write of a single value?

Comment: I am trying to read/test/write to same location but potentially different value

Comment: When you say "same location", do you mean in the same image? That's my question: are you doing a read/test/write to the same *memory* or not? Because the z-buffer algorithm uses the test to control not just writes to the z-buffer but also writes to the *color buffers*, which is different memory. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: No ,sorry that I was not clear. To be as precise as possible, I read from position (i,j,k) in the 3D texture, then potentially but not necessarily write to position (i,j,k) in the same image.

Comment: There are atomic operations in glsl that do exactly what you need.